# Passing a url value to view thru routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a url this `http://localhost/laravel/public/page/sign-up` now..

I want to get the value of the url which is "sign-up" in the view.. 
Its not including the sign-up view.. I'm just new in laravel..

and before I posted here, I have done my research and found nothing relevant

in my master.blade.php I am using this

If anybody could enlighten me what is going on here and what is lacking.. I would really appreciate it

**View**

```
@if ($page == 'sign-up')
    @include('pages/unregistred/sign-up')
@endif
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('page/{action}', function($action){ 
    return View::make('layouts.master')->with('page', $action); 
});
```

Comment: Assign a controller to the route and then you can get it via a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('page/{action}', ['as' => 'sign-up', function($action){ 
    return View::make('layouts.master')->with('page', $action); 
}]);
```

And in the layout use:

```
@if (Route::currentRouteNamed('sign-up'))
    @include('pages/unregistred/sign-up')
@endif
```

Also you can use `Route::is()` method for matching:

```
@if (Request::is('page/sign-up'))
```

Another way if the prefix of the page is `/page/`:

```
Request::segment(2); // return "sign-up"
```

Other info are in the docs: [Request Information](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information)

I suggest you to use the route to show the correct view and not include them in the layout using conditions.

You can find a guide to the layout here: [Blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('page/{type}', 'PageController@index');
```

**Controller:**

```
    class PageController extends BaseController {
        public function index($type)
        {

            return View::make('page.register', array('page' => $type));
        }
   }
```

Comment: I know but he will need a controller for data manipulation, I think it`s inevitable :)

Comment: Still not necessary even for data manipulation ;). Might turn out messy, I know, but still a powerful feature is *not* having to use controllers

Comment: I do not want to use controllers as of the moment